# How do I print out unix time, using a Qt format string?

Tags: qt, unix-timestamp

I need a Qt format string to print out unix time. I need it to be a format string because the API I'm using gives me no other choice but to pass in a format string. Otherwise I'd just take the number of seconds since the unix epoch and print it out as a number.

Comment: You could explain yourself better with an example.

Comment: This thing takes a Qt format string, one of those `"[hh:mm:ss]"` ones. I need one of those that results in the unix time, as a string.

Comment: Do you need a string similar to "1526867280 seconds since Jan 01 1970. (UTC)"? If not, please add more details about expected result.

Comment: @SoniEx2 I still do not understand you, what's your input? And what is the output you expect? Is your input a string with the format `"[hh:mm:ss]"` and what you want is the unix time?

Comment: I can give it any such format string. I just need it to output e.g. `1526867609`.

Comment: ... I'll just patch Qt, probably. seems like it'll be a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need `uint QDateTime::toTime_t() const` which returns the datetime as the number of seconds that have passed since 1970-01-01T00:00:00, Coordinated Universal Time (Qt::UTC). Another possible option is `QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch()`.

But it is not clear how do you plan to use Qt format string. So, please explain why can't you use `toTime_t()`/`currentMSecsSinceEpoch()` and what do you expect from format strings.